# imapsync: NO APPEND error saving message

Tags: imapsync

I am using imapsync 1.525 to migrate mail into zarafa 7.1.4 on ubuntu 12.04. For quite some messages (about 32000) I get the following error:

```
    Sent 7021 bytes
    Read:   219 NO APPEND error saving message
    ERROR: 219 NO APPEND error saving message at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm
    line 1363
    Mail::IMAPClient::_get_response('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)', 219,
    undef) called at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 1310
    Mail::IMAPClient::_imap_command_do('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)',
    'HASH(0x22c1eb8)', 'APPEND "INBOX/My Folder " () "25-Aug-2010
    14:58:31...') called at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 1209
    Mail::IMAPClient::_imap_command('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)',
    'HASH(0x22c1eb8)', 'APPEND "INBOX/My Folder " () "25-Aug-2010
    14:58:31...') called at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 2920
    Mail::IMAPClient::append_string('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)',
    'INBOX/My Folder ', 'Return-Path:
    <sender@senderdomain.com>\x{d}\x{a}Delivery-Date: Wed, 25 Au...', '', '"25-Aug-2010
    14:58:31 +0000"') called at /root/imapsync-1.525/imapsync line 3009
    main::copy_message(2, 'My Folder ', 'INBOX/My Folder ', 'HASH(0x2292128)', '\Seen \Draft \Deleted \Flagged \Answered
    $Forwarded', '/tmp/imapsync_cache/imap.acme.de/my.name@mydomain.com/l...')
    called at /root/imapsync-1.525/imapsync line 1490
    ERROR: 219 NO APPEND error saving message at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm
    line 1258
    Mail::IMAPClient::_imap_command('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)',
    'HASH(0x22c1eb8)', 'APPEND "INBOX/My Folder " () "25-Aug-2010
    14:58:31...') called at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 2920
    Mail::IMAPClient::append_string('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x225e3b0)',
    'INBOX/My Folder ', 'Return-Path:
    <sender@senderdomain.com>\x{d}\x{a}Delivery-Date: Wed, 25 Au...', '', '"25-Aug-2010
    14:58:31 +0000"') called at /root/imapsync-1.525/imapsync line 3009
    main::copy_message(2, 'My Folder ', 'INBOX/My Folder ', 'HASH(0x2292128)', '\Seen \Draft \Deleted \Flagged \Answered
    $Forwarded', '/tmp/imapsync_cache/imap.acme.de/my.name@mydomain.com/l...')
    called at /root/imapsync-1.525/imapsync line 1490
    - msg My Folder /2 {7019} couldn't append
    (Subject:[=?iso-8859-1?Q?AW=3A_my_subject?=])
    to folder INBOX/My Folder : 219 NO APPEND error saving message
    msg My Folder /3 copying to INBOX/My Folder 
    internal date from host1: [29-Aug-2010 22:17:42 +0000]
    internal date from host1: ["29-Aug-2010 22:17:42 +0000"] (fixed)
    msg My Folder /3 date ["29-Aug-2010 22:17:42 +0000"] flags [] size
    [1341]
```

Other messages have been migrated fine. The attachment directory has permissions for zarafa, and is abut 150G large, so I assume zarafa is successfully storing attachments there. Also there is enough space on the filesystem.

Zarafa gateway tells me (loglevel 6):

```
    Thu Apr  4 13:44:30 2013: [28997] < 219 APPEND "INBOX/My Folder " ()
    "25-Aug-2010 14:5
    8:31 +0000" {7019}
    Thu Apr  4 13:44:30 2013: [28997] > + Ready for literal data
    Thu Apr  4 13:44:30 2013: [28997] < <7019 bytes data> Return-Path: 

    <REMOVED MAIL DATA FOR PRIVACY>

    Thu Apr  4 13:44:30 2013: [28997] Trying to parse alternative multipart 1 of
    mail body
    Thu Apr  4 13:44:30 2013: [28997] > 219 NO APPEND error saving message
```

It seems strange that the folde name terminates with a whitespace ( "INBOX/My Folder " ), but that seems not to be a problem, other messages have been migrated successfully to that folder.

I wondered about the "$Forwarded" flag, which seems odd as all the other flags start with a backslash. But in a test account this flag migrated fine.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You can't get more information from Zarafa?

Comment: Well, with loglevel 6 (which is not documented) there is a little bit more. I have added it to the post.

Comment: Looks like it's having problems with the attachment, probably some file system issue.

Comment: NickW: could you please elaborate a bit, what would you check ... to make sure it is or is not a file system issue.

Comment: I'd try and up the logging level still, are attachments configured to be placed into another directory?

Comment: loglevels allready at 6, thats the maximum. Attachments are in /var/lib/zarafa/attachments, which has plenty of free space and inodes. There are about 6000 Attachments per subdir, which should be fine(?).

Comment: Yeah, any modern FS should have no problem with that. What is with the Subject of that email that blocks though? Subject:[=?iso-8859-1?Q?AW=3A_my_subject?=] maybe there are some characters that aren't liked/need to be escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was hitting zarafa quota. I found out after I looked at it with thunderbird (Gilles LAMIRAL suggested that on the imapsync maillinglist - thank you). There I saw the quota. So after raising quota in zarafa, the problem was solved.

Comment: Nice of zarafa to mention the quota in the logs..

Comment: Same thing happened with me with Zimbra.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to last Mail::IMAPClient perl module if it not the case.

What gives df commands?

```
    df /tmp
    df -i /tmp
```

/tmp can be full by inodes or space.

Comment: I upgraded to version 3.32 of Mail::IMAPClient (from 3.30). /tmp has plenty of free space and inodes. Still the same problem.